# loop through a set of tr's and escape a specific tr by index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi i want to loop through some tr's like this .

```
<tr>
 <td> <input type="radio" id="r11"   value="a" name="r1_selectedobjects" /> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r12"   value="b" name="r1_selectedobjects" /> <td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r21"   value="a" name="r2_selectedobjects" /></td>
  <input type="radio" id="r22"   value="b" name="r2_selectedobjects" /></td>
</tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r31"   value="a" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r32"   value="b" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" id="matbutton" data-inline="true"  value="Submit" onclick="return CheckMatrixRadio(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
```

i can do this by `$('tr').each(function(){});`

i want to skip the `3 rd tr`

this one

```
</tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r31"   value="a" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r32"   value="b" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
<tr>
```

how to do this . think that i don't know any calss or id names , only thing i know is index of my tr , in this case , `3`

how to skip that `tr` in my `each` loop . please help...........

Comment: You have a typo after the row containing the `r31` and `r32` radio buttons and before the row containing the submit button: You have two `<tr>` start tags in a row. Mentioning it in case you copied-and-pasted from your real markup and need to fix it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) callback receives a zero-based index telling you which matched item you're looking at, so:

```
$('tr').each(function(index){
    // If not the third one...
    if (index !== 2) {
        // ...do something
    }
});
```

If for any reason you don't want to use `each` (you mentioned it in your question, but just covering bases) but instead want to create a jQuery instance with all the rows except the third one, the most efficient way I know is:

```
var rows = $('tr');
rows = rows.not(rows[2]);
```

...which removes the third row from the matched set via [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not). You could also achieve the same thing with a selector involving [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$('tr:not(:eq(2))')
```

...but then you're requiring jQuery to process the selector rather than allowing it to pass the selector off to the browser's `querySelectorAll` implementation (if it has one). *

[Examples of all three](http://jsbin.com/acumul)

---

(Side note: If there are unrelated `tr`s anywhere on the page, you may need to make your selector more specific to the group of rows you're looking at.)

---

* PiTheNumber points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8984559/157247) that `$('tr:not(:nth-child(3))')` should do it, too. And that's useful because it has the advantage that both `:not` and `:nth-child` can be processed by the browser natively. Note that `:nth-child` uses 1-based indexes, and is *very* different from `:eq` — it checks which child an element is of its container, not whether it's the nth *matched* element. Should work for a table with `tr` elements provided they're all in the same `tbody`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the third tr using the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
$('tr:not(:nth-child(3))').each(function(index, value) {

});
```

Comment: +1 for the `:nth-child` selector. It *should* work with `tr` elements provided they're all in the same `tbody`, and since both `:not` and `:nth-child` are CSS3, if the browser supports CSS3 selectors, it could be done natively. Note that you don't need the `tr` part of `tr:nth-child` (you've already filtered for `tr` elements, and it doesn't affect the index `:nth-child` checks).

Answer (score 0):

Use Index, it's a 0 based index for the current iteration of the loop.

e.g.

```
$('tr').each(function(index){
    if(index !== 2) {
      // Do stuff here for rows that aren't the 3rd one
    }
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/each/ for more information

Answer (score 0):

First of all have a look at your markup! There is a big mistake in it. With closing your `<tr>` tags. I corrected it for you

```
<tr>
   <td> <input type="radio" id="r11"   value="a" name="r1_selectedobjects" /> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r12"   value="b" name="r1_selectedobjects" /> <td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r21"   value="a" name="r2_selectedobjects" /></td>
   <input type="radio" id="r22"   value="b" name="r2_selectedobjects" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r31"   value="a" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r32"   value="b" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="submit" id="matbutton" data-inline="true"  value="Submit" onclick="return CheckMatrixRadio(this);" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can exclude the given element in jQuery:

`$('tr:not(:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
        // function
});`

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr').not(':nth-child(3)')` will give you the result.